# How to Keep Session Even after Browser is Closed for Persistent Cookie

Tags: session-cookies, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using cookie based authentication and making it persistent when login:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>()
{
    new Claim("UserName", user.UserName)
};

var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
var props = new AuthenticationProperties()
{
    IsPersistent = true,
    IssuedUtc = utcNow,
    ExpiresUtc = utcNow.AddMinutes(60)
};

_httpcontext.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, props).Wait();
```

My configuration details:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();




services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Global/AccessDenied";
    });

services.AddAuthorization(config =>
{
    config.AddPolicy(CommonConstValues.AuthorizationPolicyName, policyBuilder =>
    {
        policyBuilder.UserRequireCustomClaim(CustomClaimTypes.UserName.ToString());
        policyBuilder.UserRequireCustomClaim(ClaimTypes.Uri);
    });
});

services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(configuration["SessionIdleTimeoutSeconds"]));
    options.IOTimeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```

Now after closing and reopening the browser when I browse the application I get the authentication is valid but Session Data is cleared. I can see the **Cookie** is there but the **HttpContext** has changed.

How to persist the session too? Did I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are inherently not persisted. In fact the use of a server-side session is not a best practice (security, scalability).

If you were to persist the session-cookie, you would also need to store all the data that you will store in the server-side session in a backend store (database, permanent redis-cache, ...) (and provision to clear out abandoned sessions)

So while not answering your question directly, please reconsider your use case for needing to store the session cookie.